# Extract array of objects into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `fetch` function which returns a json file. The source file looks like this:

```
{
    "pages":[
        {
            "page": "people.html",
            "title": "People"
        },
        {
            "page": "client.html",
            "title": "Client"
        }
    ]   

}
```

When the response from the `fetch` (after applying `.json()`) it is a array of multiple objectives, each with two strings:

```
0 
title: "People Policies"
page: "people.html"

1
title: "Client Policies"
page: "client.html"
```

where 0 and 1 are OBJECTS and title/page the strings.

Question: how can I extract the objects into a simple array (not objects) with multiple key pairs or is there another way to format the source file?

There are plenty of questions on here with similar questions but I just can't get any of them to work, including `Object.entries(obj)`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your expected result? how should the output look like?

Comment: Can you please add your expected result? how should the output look like?

Comment: Add your desired output

Comment: `data.map(Object.entries)`?

Comment: Expected result would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your question is that your source data is an array of objects each having two string values. And after .json(), you're getting an indexed object like

```
{
 0: {
   // ....
   }
}
```

In this case, you can try Object.values() like

```
fetch(some_url).then(resp => resp.json()).then(resp => {
    // resp is your object
    let formattedArray = Object.values(resp);
    console.log(formattedArray)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {
    "pages":[
        {
            "page": "people.html",
            "title": "People"
        },
        {
            "page": "client.html",
            "title": "Client"
        }
    ]   

}


const pages = data.pages.map(obj => obj.pages)
const titles = data.pages.map(obj => obj.title)
```

Not sure which one you wanted in an array so heres both.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const json = {
    "pages":[
        {
            "page": "people.html",
            "title": "People"
        },
        {
            "page": "client.html",
            "title": "Client"
        }
    ]   
}

const addObj = json.pages

for (el of json.pages) {
  console.log('key-value pairs:', Object.entries(el), '; keys:', Object.keys(el), '; values:', Object.values(el))
}
```